# How do I upgrade Django 1.3.1 to 1.4? Any tips, tutorials, or warnings?

Tags: python, django, gentoo, virtualenv

[Django 1.4](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/mar/23/14/) was recently released. Almost all the information about Django 1.4 is in the release note, but I didn't see anything about how to upgrade. Should I just remove the `django` folder inside Python's `site-packges` and download 1.4? I think I originally installed Django using `emerge` and `yum` but I'm not sure if the package management systems are up-to-date with Django 1.4 yet.

That might be ok on my server instance (Gentoo Linux), but on my local instance I am using [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) (on Mac OS 10.7), so maybe I want to create a new Python virtual environment for Djago 1.4. Or maybe not since I don't really care about backward compatibility with 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a backup
2. Someone suggested on stackoverflow:

*I usually create a symlink from my Python site-packages directory to the Django version I am using. When I change versions I merely change the symlink to point at the right version. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-the-development-version) for creating a symlink. The docs mention the development version but you can do it for any version.*

[Original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450575/django-how-to-upgrade-from-1-1-to-1-2)